# how do you make enums work with simple_form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, enums, simple-form

Please consider the following model

```
  class Song < ActiveRecord::Base

      enum category: [:english, :french]

      enum file_type: [:mp3, :video]

      enum mood: [:sad, :happy]
    end
```

I have a form

```
= simple_form_for(@song) do |f|

  = f.input :name
  = f.input :category, collection: Song.categories
  = f.input :file_type, collection: Song.file_types
  = f.input :mood, collection: Song.moods
```

Here is the problem is when i edit the form then the selected value is nil i.e the select box doesnt select the value that was set instead it selects blank. So i am wondering in the view is there a way to show the saved enum value?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try. `collection: Song.categories.keys`?

Comment: thanks that did it. put it in answer and i will accept it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass the keys to the collection instead of the enum.

`= f.input :category, collection: Song.categories.keys`